# Prevent htaccess 301 redirects on sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have 301 redirects which direct /index.html to /site folder and when i created a sub-domain it also redirects the link to /site which causes 404 Not Found

For example: members.mysite.com redirects to members.mysite/site which causes 404 error can I add execption for specific forlder or something without changing the redirect.

**.htaccess content**

```
AddType text/x-server-parsed-html .htm .html
RedirectMatch 301  ^/index.html(.*)$ /site$1
```

Comment: set sub-domain's document root somewhere other than main domain's document root **OR** use rewrite-mod to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to check for the host:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-main.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.html(.*)$ /site$1 [R=301,L]
```

Take a look at the [`RewriteCond` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for a better description of its functionality. You can tailor the regular expression (`^your-main.domain.com$`) to fit more along the lines of your needs, like adding a `(www\.)?` in front to handle an optional "www".

Comment: thank you I couldnt work it your way but i tried `Redirect permanent index.html /site/` and the sub-domain worked fine i wanted to know whats the difference between this and the one i was uisng before? does hurt google analytics the ?

Comment: @Ahmedk No, the difference with what you were doing with `Redirect` is that it doesn't check what host someone is trying to access. From your question, it looked like both hosts were served by the same host, so you would need to check if it's the main site before redirecting in order to prevent the subdomain from also redirecting.

Comment: it didnt work, i thought it worked but it was working then when i checked again it didnt work (the redirect) and the sub-domain was working i tried your solution again it works when i get my site.com goes to mysite.com/site but when try members.mysite.com it stills goes to members.mysite.com/site i just dont want /site to be added when requesting the sub-domain

Comment: the `RewriteCond` must match the host to **only the main domain, not any subdomain**, if it matches a the subdomain it will redirect it. That regular expression must ONLY match the main domain, if it does, the subdomain won't get redirected.

Comment: at last i guess it worked ! i changed the last line to `RewriteRule (.*) /site$1 [R=301,L]` removed the ^index.html maybe that was preventing it,its working but if i typed mysite.com/any-wrong-url it redirects to mysite/sitesitesitesitesitesitesite loop redirect i guess and it doesnt display the 404 error page can i disable it Thank you for your help

Comment: Try adding this right before the `RewriteRule` then: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site%{REQUEST_URI} -f`

Comment: ok it stopped the redirect loop but the site cant redirect from **mydomain.com to mydomain.com/site** only the sub-domain works! last configuration as follows `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*) /site$1 [R=301,L]` do you see any cause? thank you for your help